# Why is GWL_WNDPROC undefined?

Tags: c++

This is the only error I'm receiving, and can't seem to find a fix for it. `windows.h` and `Winuser.h` are included, so I don't think it's that.

```
DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID param)
{
    HWND  window = FindWindowA(NULL, windowName);

    oWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(window, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)WndProc);

    IDirect3D9 * pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    if (!pD3D)
        return false;

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp{ 0 };
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = window, d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD , d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;

    IDirect3DDevice9 *Device = nullptr;
    if (FAILED(pD3D->CreateDevice(0, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, d3dpp.hDeviceWindow, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &Device)))
    {
        pD3D->Release();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: "windows.h and Winuser.h are included in VB" -- I'm sorry, what?

Comment: [Per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw), `SetWindowLongPtr` takes `GWLP_WNDPROC` (among others). Note the extra `P`.

Comment: @rory.ap Had to include them, my directories for some reason were not including them automatically. (Sorry for bad english!)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So is this error false?

Comment: The error is true. Your code uses the wrong name.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah sorry i was not understanding, you've helped me fix it, thank you!

Comment: @Jynzxs Are you building for 64bit? `GWL_WNDPROC` is not defined in a 64bit build, but `GWLP_WNDPROC` is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was building for 64 bit! My mistake, should've caught it sooner

Answer (score 7):

When using `SetWindowLongPtr()`, the correct value to use is `GWLP_WNDPROC`, not `GWL_WNDPROC`, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra). `GWL_WNDPROC` is used with `SetWindowLong()` instead.

`GWL_WNDPROC` and `GWLP_WNDPROC` are both defined in `winuser.h`. However, `GWL_WNDPROC` is *not* defined if `_WIN64` is defined. Which makes sense, as `SetWindowLong()` is not available in a 64-bit flavor. `SetWindowLongPtr()` was introduced to support 64-bit.